# Relación extraña con Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Estoy haciendo una pequeña aplicación Java con Hibernate para venta de clases particulares.

Clases implicadas: Profesores, Cursos, Venta, LineasVenta.

Mi problema es que no se como relacionar LineasVenta con Profesor porque una linea puede tener un profesor asignado si el alumno lo solicita sino no.

Querría tener un campo de clase Profesor en LineasVenta pero que puede ser null.

Y tampoco tengo clara la relación ya que una LineaVenta solo puede tener un Profesor, pero este puede tener muchas LineasVenta. Y no me interesa tener en la clase Profesor un List con todas las lineas que tiene incluso aunque el aceso sea LAZY, ya que pasados unos años la lista puede ser descomunal.

¿ Cómo lo abordaríais vosotros ?

Comment: ¿Tienes la relación de las tablas?

Comment: Que yo sepa, puedes tenerlo como pides. Haces una relacion de 1 profesor a muchas lineas de venta, donde en `lineasVenta` tienes un objeto de tipo profesor. Y al profesor no le añades la lista, y deberia de funcionar

Comment: Desde LineaVentas tendrias un @ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY). No me queda claro que es linea de venta, pero si un profesor puede tener mas de 10, no haría el mapeo inverso de @OneToMany.

Comment: Hola Juan, no me queda muy claro esto que dices: "pero si un profesor puede tener mas de 10, no haría el mapeo inverso de @OneToMany."